# Simple use of Python’s Subprocess.call to open multiple Mac apps

Tags: python, macos

I’d like to open a few apps using a very simple python script:

```
from subprocess import call
call("/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome")
call("/Applications/MongoDB Compass.app/Contents/MacOS/MongoDB Compass")
```

The problem is that opening them this way seems to open a terminal window along with the app itself - for chrome, it outputs this in the terminal for example:

```
Last login: Sun Oct 23 00:20:38 on ttys000
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome ; exit;
nick@Nicks-MBP ~ % /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome ; exit;
objc[3817]: Class WebSwapCGLLayer is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/WebCore.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/libANGLE-shared.dylib (0x7ffb45565ec8) and /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Frameworks/Google Chrome Framework.framework/Versions/106.0.5249.119/Libraries/libGLESv2.dylib (0x116ba9668). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

So it hijacks the terminal and does not proceed to this next line:

```
call("/Applications/MongoDB Compass.app/Contents/MacOS/MongoDB Compass")
```

If I try to call these:

```
call(("/Applications/Google Chrome.app"))
call(("/Applications/MongoDB Compass.app"))
```

I get this error, with other posts stating that it may be a dir and not an app:

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

How can this be fixed? Note that I do not want to do this despite it working:

```
os.system("open /Applications/" + app + ".app")
```

Because I need to be able to wait for the apps to finish opening before running another command, hence the use of `Subprocess.call`. Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

I now have this:

```
print("start")
call(
    [("/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome")],
    shell=True,
    stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL,
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
)
print("end")
```

But the `print("end")` line only executes when I exit out of chrome. How can I get it to wait for Chrome to load and then print 'end' after? Also it requires `Shell=True` for some reason, otherwise it complains with:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Applications/Google\\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\\ Chrome
```

Comment: When you run an application this way, `call()` doesn't return until the application exits. It doesn't return when the application has finished opening.

Comment: You should be able to use the `stdout` and `stderr` options to `subproces.call()` to redirect the output so it doesn't open the terminal.

Comment: How can that be done? I've tried passing in `None` to them both, or `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` but the output still hijacks the terminal

Comment: `stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`

Comment: I don't get a new terminal window opened. I get the messages in the same terminal window where I'm running Python. And as I said, `subprocess.call()` doesn't return until I quit out of the browser.

Comment: Interesting comments, thank you. Is there any way of running chrome, waiting for it to finish loading and the continue? I have updated my answer with what happens now after implementing your changes

Comment: There might be some way using AppleScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

This also appears to work and doesn't involve the shell:

```
import subprocess as sp
print("start")
sp.run(["open", "-a", "Google Chrome"])
print("end")
```

**Original Answer**

This appears to do what you want, though I have no explanation as to why:

```
import subprocess as sp

print("start")
sp.Popen(
   ["/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"],
   stdin =sp.DEVNULL,
   stdout=sp.DEVNULL,
   stderr=sp.DEVNULL)
print("end")
```

Comment: You have to remove the escaping from the command name (i.e. `Google Chrome.app`) and replace `subprocess` by `sp`

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano Ooops, yes, thank you. I was testing in an Python session where I had previously imported `subprocess` completely!